# How to pick an html 'a' <a> tag using php, especially by POST or GET technique?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Suppose I have a code like this in my page

```
<a href="some_url" name="" value=""> Jokes</a>
<a href="some_url" name="" value=""> Quotes</a>
```

Now If I click on one of these links, say I clicked the 'Jokes' link, I want to pick up the 'Jokes' category through POST or GET method of php and compare it my categories in MYSQL database. If there is a match, then I want to display certain details.

Please help me on how to proceed with this.

Comment: You should learn some basic HTML, and web basis in general, before going PHP. That's the only sensitive advice you shall be given right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to construct the `some_url` to have parameters on it that relate to the Joke category. For example

`<a href="http://www.example.com/show.php?category=jokes">Jokes</a>`

`<a href="http://www.example.com/show.php?category=quotes">Quotes</a>`

Then in your script (let's say `show.php` you would query the `$_GET['category']` parameter and use that to compare against your database records.

**Make sure you sanitize all GET and POST parameters prior to them being used in a database query** (or for any other purpose really). You can not trust that input from the user will be friendly. Refer to [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for information about escaping dangerous characters, or better yet, use [PDO with prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

I'm not sure if `name` and `value` are valid attributes of an `<a>` tag.

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja But it has got quite a different meaning from the one seeming to be used here (among with 'value' seems like the 'name' attr you find in 'input' tags). There's a lot of confusion here and the OP should really scratch start from basic HTML.

Comment: The "name" attribute is deprecated since HTML5. I think search engines might still use it though. @gd1 I agree

Comment: +1 for the obviously correct advice, but such a trial-and-error approach of the OP can bring to severe problems, until he learns some basic stuff. @matthewh just look at your answer, from "then" to "database records". What you think it will happen in the script of the OP? I see a giant SQL injection potentially going on...

Comment: @gd1 You're right, I'm assuming a level of knowledge that the OP may not have. I'll edit my answer to include a warning of SQL injection.

Comment: @gd1: Agreed, but link parameters aren't something to learn form basic HTML since they have no meaning in static content.

Comment: Thats not my question.. I want to know, like how you pick the radio-button values using $_POST['radio_name'] and compare with its value, I want to go in a similar way for html 'a' tags!

Comment: @JennyDcosta you can't, because 'a' tags aren't part of a form input and thus aren't submitted to the server.

Comment: ok..then how do I proceed without the fear of sql-injections?

Comment: I edited my post to include links to the manual showing you how to ensure data is clean before using it.

Comment: ok..I know abt those procedures.. here I m posting my php code    <?php
$queery="Select cat_name FROM feed_categories";
$daata=mysqli_query($dbc,$queery);
while($roow=mysqli_fetch_array($daata))
{
echo'<a class="top" href="viewcom.php?category='.$roow['cat_name'].'" name="'.$roow['cat_name'].'">'.$roow['cat_name'].'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';

}

Comment: $query3="SELECT si.user_name, ld.link_desc,ld.link_url,fc.cat_name FROM si_table as si inner join link_desp as ld inner join feed_categories as fc on 

si.user_id=ld.user_id and ld.cat_id=fc.cat_id WHERE fc.cat_name= '.$_GET['category'].'";

$data3=mysqli_query($dbc,$query3);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data3))

{
echo'<p><a href="'.$row['link_url'].'"> '.$row['link_desc'].'</a> <br/> submitted by '.$row['user_name'].' </p>';

}

Comment: That's right, but once again, you need to make sure `$_GET['category']` is sanitized before using it in a query.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$category = $_GET['category'];

?>
```